# Audio glitch like if it's trying to sync back

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, audio

Currently when playing back audio and/or video I get some weird audio glitches like the sound in syncing back with the picture. When playing back just audio the issue appears.

I'm using Media Player Classic from the CCCP codec pack.

The problem happens also in Firefox with Flash on YouTube, and Google Chrome without Flash (still on YouTube).

I'm also running Window 8.1 64bits and nothing changed since this week.

Comment: looks like DPC issue: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140263

Comment: In LatencyMon I have 139136 reported hard pagefault, and I often have `storport.sys` as the highest reported ISR routine execution time (391 on the last run). For the highest DPC I often have the `ndis.sys` (1279 on the last run). I have added a hard drive on my Asus ROG G750JM more than a month ago and the SMART data doesn't report any problems. For the network I'm currently wired and have had the WiFi still on since I move around sometimes, should I disable it when plugged in ?

Comment: try to disable the Wifi. storport.sys sounds like SATA driver. Do you use the inbox Microsoft driver or a driver from the vendor (AMD, Intel, nVIDIA)?

Comment: Currently I have disabled the WiFi since I'm using a cable. I have not installed a driver for the wifi or the drives since I installed Windows. According to DriverView by Nirsoft I'm using Broadcom's driver, for the storage I can't figure out if I'm using one. Here is the [CSV of my drivers](http://pastebin.com/0EKUUMxj), and an [HTML view](http://static.senpaisilver.com/rog_drivers.htm).

Comment: share the generated ETL file from xperf, so that I can see more details.

Comment: I have reinstalled the Realtek drivers to try and the issue seems resolved for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reinstalled the Realtek drivers and the issue is fixed for the moment.